# How I can get SQL dump

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-server-2008

I use query builder, can someone tell me how I can get the result of SQL statement from that query builder.

My query builder,

```
$this->db->join('kategori_produk', 'produk.KategoriID = kategori_produk.KategoriID');
            $this->db->where('MerchantID', $merchantID);
            $this->db->order_by($order_column, $order_type);
            $this->db->like($searchField, $search);
        }
```

Because I don't get the result like expected, instead write query manually

Comment: Please print_r() your result to check.

Comment: it would help *a lot* if you could tell which type is `db` object. like as in, afterwards, your question would be very easy to answer.

Comment: You are missing your select() and from() and get() http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join

Answer (score -1, accepted):

refer this link to write query
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

to echo the query use this

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

before return the result

Comment: sorry, it's my first question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following code directly in your controller, it would show the queries the system build.

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Also the above can show the data posts, session variables, query time, and so on. It's helpful.

Comment: how about in view, not necessary echo or something ?

Comment: @ahmadryuzaki It also works fine in view. Just paste `<?php $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); ?>` without `echo`.